# Java deciphering UML diagram

Tags: java, class-diagram

[image]

I have to write  a program which computes the prime factors of a number. I have the algorithm done already, I just don't see how to use the methods hasMoreFactors and nextFactor. Here's my algorithm inside the constructor

```
int i = 2;

while (num > 1)
{
    if (num % i == 0)
    {
      System.out.println(i); // test if algorithm works
      factor.add(i);        // adds factor to array list
    }
else
{
  i++;
}
```

My hunch is that I have to use hasMoreFactors in the algorithm, so I would replace this:

```
if (num % i == 0)
```

with hasMoreFactors().

```
if (hasMoreFactors() == true)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is the iterator pattern. You are supplying an iteratable data type `Factors`. That means the client of your code will be passing it a number to get all the calculated factors and then will retrieve them.

The two methods you have questions about are not for you to use *per-se*; they need not be used in the code calculating the factors. They are part of the interface the client uses to get those calculated numbers.

You *do* need to implement them which is another question. The primary hint given to you is that you need to keep track of the current index the user is at.

Taking a look at the [Java Iterator interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) may be of some help.